# SAS: Import excel where column names are over 32 characters

Tags: excel, import, sas

I am using the import tool in SAS Enterprise guide to import an excel file
Some columns have more than 32 characters.
The problem is that when these column get truncated, they end up having the same name and therefore some are not included in the import.

An example would be:

```
thisisacolumnnamewithmorethanthirtytwocharactersEXAMPLE1
thisisacolumnnamewithmorethanthirtytwocharactersEXAMPLE2
```

The truncated version of these two columns is

```
thisisacolumnnamewithmorethanthir
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable if all columns are read, but have arbitrary names? (e.g., var1, var2...)

Comment: it could... but then I'd have to rename them all. Say I add one more column in the middle of the file, that becomes a pain

Comment: PROC IMPORT will correctly read all columns, even if they're named the same - at least it does when I test it with both DBMS=EXCEL and DBMS=XLSX.  Have you tried that?  Or do you not have access to PC files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's not possible using the import tool, unless you don't use column headings for variable names.  You will have to rename the vars explicitly after the import has been performed.  I thought there may be an option for variable names to be longer than 32 chars but even changing the validvarname system option does not provide a means to go longer than 32 chars:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000279245.htm